# pygame - trying to move a rectangle

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am codding a drum game (based on dtx-Mania).

I got an issue on how to draw a rectangle and move it. I can make a static one, but not a moving one. I currently used a line but it seams pygame draw it as a rectangle so far if it as an impact i will change back to rectangle.

My goal is to draw the rectangle and move it at a slow enough pace so that it takes about 1 second to get to a line.

I know I still have a lot to learn, this is what I got to test so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
#small exemple of a moving rectangle
import pygame, sys
pygame.init()
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()
windowsSurfaceObj = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
pygame.display.set_caption('moving rectangle test')
white = pygame.Color(255, 255, 255)
black = pygame.Color(0, 0, 0)
step = pygame.draw.line(windowsSurfaceObj, white, (233, 0), (269, 0), 6)
step
while True:
    windowsSurfaceObj.fill(black)
    #the coordonate are moved but the rectangle is now drew
    step.move(0, -1)
    #this is the target line (where the moving object must go to)
    pygame.draw.line(windowsSurfaceObj, white, (90, 420), (390, 420), 6)
    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(30)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: nope, changing line to an actual rectangle did not work ... still  looking

Answer (score 0):

It is always good to read the docs. From the pygame docs:

> line(Surface, color, start_pos, end_pos, width=1) -> Rect
>
> Draw a straight line segment on a Surface. There are no endcaps, the
>   ends are squared off for thick lines.

In the description text of the whole module:

```
The functions return a rectangle representing the bounding area of changed pixels.
```

So you draw your first line, and move a rectangle representing a bounding are of changed pixels. Since you do not redraw your line, your first line disappears.

To solve this, you need to draw the line in the while loop after moving.

```
step.move(0, -1)
pygame.draw.rect(windowsSurfaceObj, white,step, 6)
```